# Unexpected with enum class

Tags: c++11

I'm getting a strange error with
`enum class` declaration. Here is an example:

```
enum class TESTING

{ ONE, TWO, THREE};

class Testing_User{

    ...

    TESTING t;

};
```

The compiler shows me on the second line of enum declaration:

```
error: expected '}' before '('

note: to match this '{'
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code.
I'm using codeblocks 20, gcc 10, Win10

Thanks for your time and support

Comment: Please post a [mre], I can't [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/fzexbn) your error (note that there's no `(` in the posted code).

Comment: Do you by chance have a preprocessor define `ONE`, `TWO` or `THREE`?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your kind reply, It was about NAN, once I removed it from the enumeration all worked well... Thanks a lot for time

Comment: There has been no `NAN` in the code you have posted here...?

Comment: No, I didn't expect that having a NAN in my code could make this kind of error... So I just removed it since your first question was an hint and it really helped me.